# A faithful algebro-geometric action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, representation-theory, group-actions

I'm currently going through this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.5522.pdf, and having some (a lot of!) trouble understanding the proof given to the following (this is Lemma 4 in the article):

Let $X$ be an irreducible variety (i.e. a space with functions having a finite open cover of affine sets) over a field of characteristic $0$, and let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$; the group of automorphisms of $X$. If $P\in X$ is fixed by $G$, then the natural action $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)$ is faithful, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathscr{O}_{X,P}$.

---

It suffices to prove that ker$\rho$ acts trivially on $\mathfrak{m}$ for then it acts trivially on $\mathscr{O}_{X,P}\cong k \oplus \mathfrak{m}$, hence on its field of fractions $k(X)$ ($X$ is irreducible), hence on $X$. Then ker$\rho$ is trivial since it also acts faithfully on $X$.

My plan: Since $G$ is finite and the characteristic is zero, Maschke's theorem applies: there exists a subrepresentation $V$ of $\mathfrak{m}$ isomorphic to $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. Then ker$\rho$ acts trivially on $V$.

The passage to the action on $\mathfrak{m}$ is where I'm stuck at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the next step is to show that the subspace $V^d$ generated by all products of $1$ to $d$ elements of $V$ surjects (in a $G$-equivariant way) into $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{d+1}$. Now the kernel $K$ of $\rho$ acts trivially on $V$ so on $V^d$ too, and thus $K$ acts trivially on $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{d+1}$.

Let $f \in \mathfrak{m}$, it follows from the above that, if $t \in K$, $t \cdot f-f \in \cap_{d \geq 1}{\mathfrak{m}^d}$ which is zero by Krull’s theorem. Thus $K$ acts trivially on $\mathfrak{m}$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide more details? For example, the way you describe V^d is not the same as in the article. Also, in the article, it is implied that V^d is a subspace of m, which is certainly not true. Lastly, in what way was Nakayama's lemma used in the proof?

Comment: My $V$ is their $L$ but my $V^d$ is the sum of their $L^k$ for $k \leq d$. Note that $L^d$ is the *linear span* of something, so is a subspace of $\mathfrak{m}$. I’m not sure where they use Nakayama’s lemma. IMHO this rephrasing of the proof is better than what is in the article (which isn’t very clear on the details – for instance their $L^d$ is contained in $\mathfrak{m}^d$ so it doesn’t span $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^{d+1}$).